# Applescript - how to access top level handler function from inside tell Application

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, handler

I'm trying to write a custom Apple Script which opens an application (Slack), and runs a check to make sure it is fully loaded before continuing. I am currently getting an error:

`Slack got an error: Can’t continue processCheck. -1708`

1708 being the error: `The script doesn’t understand the <message> message. The event was not handled.`

Here is my code:

```
tell application "Slack" to activate
global is_loaded
set is_loaded to false

processCheck()

on processCheck()
    tell application "System Events" to get name of every process
    if the result contains "Slack" then
        log "running"
        tell application "Slack"
            if (count of windows) > 0 then
                set window_name to name of front window
                log window_name
                #when window_name is just Slack, it should mean Slack is still loading
                if window_name is equal to "Slack" then
                    log "loading"
                    delay 0.5
                    if is_loaded is equal to false then
                        processCheck()
                    end if
                else
                    is_loaded = true
                    #if it is something else, it should mean Slack has loaded the user's default workspace
                    log "loaded"
                end if
            end if
        end tell
    else
        log "not running"
        delay 5
        processCheck()
    end if
end processCheck
```

I think what is happening is that my script thinks that I'm trying to tell Slack to run the function `processCheck()`, but really I'm trying to just tell my apple script to run `processCheck()`.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common error.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH):

> To call a handler from within a `tell` statement, you must use the reserved words `of me` or `my` to indicate that the handler is part of the script and not a command that should be sent to the target of the `tell` statement.

```
my processCheck()
```